# Последняя итерация foreach

Tags: c#, циклы

Можно ли узнать, используя `foreach`, что текущая итерация последняя?

Comment: Вам такого, по идее, не должно хотеться. Какая ваша настоящая задача?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Самый простой способ - добавить переменную с инкрементом на каждой итерации и проверять её соответствие свойству `Count` контейнера. Однако в этом случае цикл `foreach` фактически превращается в обычный `for`.

При этом `foreach` заточен на прогон по всем элементам и выполнения одинаковых действий вне зависимости от позиции элемента. Если подобный вопрос у Вас возник, то значит что-то не так с дизайном. Лучше использовать обычный `for`.

Comment: Обращаю внимание, что при использовании `Count()`, фактически, будет прогнан ещё один `foreach` по коллекции (если она не List).

Comment: @Qwertiy, если не ICollection<T> или ICollection

Comment: @Grundy, да, [действительно](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1193). Вроде раньше там IList видел...

Comment: @Qwertiy под `Count` я имел в виду свойство конкретного контейнера, а не Linqовский расширяющий метод. Убрал скобочки, которых не должно быть для свойства. Сказывается плюсовое мышление :)

Comment: @Qwertiy shortcut с `IList` есть в методах, которые работают с индексами, типа `First()`, `ElementAt()`, `Single()` и т.д.

Comment: @alexolut, как и наличие одноимённых свойств и метода :)

Answer (score 5):

Если очень нужно, вот вам универсальный extension-метод:

```
struct Entry<T>
{
    public T Value;
    public bool IsFirst;
    public bool IsLast;
}

static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Entry<T>> WithFirstLast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq)
    {
        using (var en = seq.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (en.MoveNext())
            {
                bool isFirst = true;
                Entry<T> entry = new Entry<T>();
                do
                {
                    entry.Value = en.Current;
                    entry.IsFirst = isFirst;
                    entry.IsLast = !en.MoveNext();
                    yield return entry;
                    isFirst = false;
                }
                while (!entry.IsLast);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Пользоваться так:

```
foreach (var v in new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }.WithFirstLast())
{
    if (v.IsFirst) Console.Write("First: ");
    if (v.IsLast) Console.Write("Last: ");
    Console.WriteLine(v.Value);
}
```

---

Этот алгоритм по сути изложен в более раннем ответе @Qwertiy. У меня добавлен лишь extension-метод.

Comment: О! Чем-то похоже на мой последний вариант. Только эм... `using (var en = seq.GetEnumerator())` - он точно обязан быть IDisposable? И ещё, смахивает на отказ от неупакованных енумераторов-структур из-за приведения к `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Вроде бы да: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb(v=vs.110).aspx. У меня компилируется™

Comment: @Qwertiy: Это да, боксирование. Но весь LINQ такой, такшта...

Comment: Да, точно. Но foreach несколько более всеядный, чем IEnumarabe, поэтому в моём варианте `as` :) Надеюсь, не напортачил там?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Это да, в принципе твой вариант. Сначала написал, потом увидел. Но у меня там extension method, так что пусть висит. Допишу в ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Вроде всё правильно. Изящная конструкция `using (enumerator as IDisposable)`, кстати.

Comment: Ага, но её почему-то редко вспоминают)))

Comment: @VladD, а как она раскрывается? где-то хранится значение этого as?

Comment: @Grundy, using вообще хранит переменную. Поэтому у него проблемы со структурами. И ой... А оно точно работает?)))

Comment: Хм.. Вроде работает и с классом: http://ideone.com/OzZI89, и со структурой: http://ideone.com/d2rvKT. Или я что-то делаю не так? Пошли тогда в комменты к моему ответу?

Answer (score 4):

В общем случае - никак. Цикл foreach использует протокол интерфейса IEnumerator - а тот не позволяет узнать о наличии следующей итерации кроме как попытавшись начать ее.

В частном случае можно сделать ToList или ToArray, после чего воспользоваться циклом for.

Или можно попытаться переписать алгоритм так, чтобы проверка на последнюю итерацию не требовалась.

Answer (score 2):

Можно самому сохранять значение во внешнюю переменную и запаздывать на один элемент:

http://ideone.com/Fz16u8

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var items = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

        int item = 0;

        foreach(var x in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
            item = x;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("{0} is the last one", item);
    }
}
```

Ещё можно развернуть цикл `foreach` руками и внести в него пару изменений:

http://ideone.com/nWKeJY

UPDATE: [Как оказалось](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/589065/178988), использовать using-as в следующем коде несколько неправильно и его следует заменить на try-finally.

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var items = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

        var enumerator = items.GetEnumerator();

        using (enumerator as IDisposable)
        {
            var exists = enumerator.MoveNext();

            if (exists)
            {
                do
                {
                    var item = enumerator.Current;
                    exists = enumerator.MoveNext();

                    Console.WriteLine(exists ? "{0}" : "{0} is the last one", item);
                }
                while (exists);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: тогда item должен быть nullable - мало ли какие допустимые значения есть, и ты никак не узнаешь была ли первая итерация или нет

Comment: @Grundy, хм.. В принципе да, но думаю, лучше каким-нибудь Contains() проверить, тем более, если там объекты, то null может тоже быть допустимым.

Comment: что-то оказалось не так просто как я думал :)

Comment: @Grundy, я "упростил" :D

Comment: Вроде работает и с классом: http://ideone.com/OzZI89, и со структурой: http://ideone.com/d2rvKT.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Должно работать, а почему ему не работать?

Comment: @VladD, она же копируется при боксинге? Или это не страшно?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Копируется, да. Но она ж копировалась при возврате из GetEnumerator тоже?

Comment: @VladD, http://ideone.com/IaIkrC - мы итерируемся по одной структуре, а Dispose вызываем на другой. И при этом структура изменяемая. Точно нормально? В [хабропримере](https://habrahabr.ru/post/209914/) упаковка идёт после использования.

Comment: @VladD, а задам-ка я отдельным вопросом.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, хм. Хороший вопрос. Может быть, тогда лучше сбоксировать раньше? Но да, стоит отдельного вопроса.

Comment: @VladD, готово: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/589065/178988.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ага, уже увидел.