# Опасно ли разворачивать foreach через using as

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, foreach, language-lawyer, дизайн-языка

В C# цикл foreach [разворачивается](https://habrahabr.ru/post/209914/) в нечто такое:

```
Container container = new Container();
Enumerator enumerator = container.GetEnumerator();

try
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var element = enumerator.Current;
        // содержимое foreach
    }
}
finally
{
    IDisposable disposable = enumerator as IDisposable;
    if (disposable != null)
        disposable.Dispose();
}
```

Насколько безопасно и корректно изменить эту реализацию на такую:

```
Container container = new Container();
Enumerator enumerator = container.GetEnumerator();

using (enumerator as IDisposable)
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var element = enumerator.Current;
        // содержимое foreach
    }
}
```

Понятно, что для reference-типов никакой разницы нет.

Но если энумератор окажется value-типом, то при приведении к IDisposable он упаковывается, что означает копирование структуры. Значит мы уничтожаем не ту же структуру, которую использовали. На этом моменте и возникает различие между приведёнными вариантами: в оригинальном структура скопирована *после* использования, а в модифицированном - *перед*.

Может ли такое различие привести к опасным последствиям? Если да, то к каким?

Comment: стоит продублировать на en мне кажется :)

Comment: "уничтожаем"? - вызываем метод `Dispose`

Comment: [Связанный вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/588902/178988) и [пример](http://ideone.com/IaIkrC).

Comment: @Igor, да, я о Dispose.

Comment: поскольку будет вызван правильный метод Dispose, о какой опасности идет речь? а, кажется понял

Comment: @Igor: Но он же будет вызван не у той же самой сущности?

Comment: @VladD, а можно как-то посмотреть во что конкретно развернется этот код?

Comment: @Igor, структура же изменяемая.

Comment: @Grundy: ILSpy умеет, только в настройках надо поотключать, чтобы он всё не собрал снова в foreach/using/...

Comment: А как можно рассматривать код _развёрнутой_ структуры, через призму _неразвёрнутой_? Вы бы хоть приводили реализацию полностью, а не через `using`.

Comment: @ixSci, но я в коде хочу using... А то вдруг я и при его разворачивании граблей соберу? ):(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Фактически, ваш вопрос сводится к тому, что надо придумать непротиворечивый и не надуманный вариант реализации `Enumerator` причём такой, чтобы

1. была реальная необходимость реализации в нём `Dispose`
2. в процессе итерирования данные, которые в нём хранятся, менялись

Сделав над собой героическое усилие и заставив себя оставить в тылу мысль о том, что "так" делать нельзя никогда, попробуем.

Для того, чтобы обосновать необходимость реализации `IDisposable` можно представить себе итератор, который возвращает данные через какой-нибудь неуправляемой `handle`. Подойдёт, например, файл.

```
public struct LineEnumerator : IEnumerator
{
    private System.IO.FileStream _file;

    public LineEnumerator(string path)
    {
        _file = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path);
    }

    IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        if (_file != null)
        {
            _file.Dispose();
            _file = null;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

После того, как мы непоправимо испортили себе карму таким итератором, выполнить второе условие очень легко. Представьте итератор, который смотрит не на файл, а на папку и по мере итерирования открывает файлы в указанной папке последовательно. Кончаются данные в одном файле, он закрывает его и открывает следующий. Таким образом, в процессе итерирования `handle` периодически меняется.

```
public struct LineEnumerator : IEnumerator
{
    private string _directoryPath;
    private System.IO.FileStream _file;

    public LineEnumerator(string directoryPath)
    {
        _directoryPath = directoryPath;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (CheckEOF(_file))
        {
            OpenNextFile(_directoryPath, ref _file);
        }

        ...
    }

    IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        if (_file != null)
        {
            _file.Dispose();
            _file = null;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Заблаговременно делать копию с такого итератора уже нельзя, если мы не хотим потерять `handle` на файл.

Отсюда мораль: нет ни одной причины реализовывать такой нумератор как `struct`. Я бы даже сказал, что нет ни одного оправдания использованию `struct` по сравнению с `class` в данном случае.

Comment: По модулю того, что `File.Read` [возвращает `FileStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.file.openread(v=vs.110).aspx) — в этом примере проблемы не будет, т. к. при копировании структуры ссылка на stream тоже скопируется.

Comment: @VladD Извините за недопечатку. Как раз таки проблема будет. Во время первого копирования скопируется ссылка на первый файл. А итератор уже успел закрыть первый файл и открыть другой.

Comment: Ну конструктор-то при копировании вызываться не будет всё равно. Обе структуры будут содержать ссылку на тот же файл.

Comment: @VladD Я же не зря описал не одно условие, а два. Рассчитывал на то, что по описанию выполнения второго условия вы додумаете код. Я ошибся. Расписал код для выполнения второго условия.

Comment: *"Отсюда мораль: нет ни одной причины реализовывать такой нумератор как struct. Я бы даже сказал, что нет ни одного оправдания использованию struct по сравнению с class в данном случае."* - да, но код должен корректно работать или корректно падать *на любых входных данных*.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Да я двумя руками за. Но вопрос сейчас не про обработку нештатных ситуаций. Однако, я счел необходимым высказать свое неодобрение `struct` для нумератора, безотносительно того, реализованы необходимые проверки или нет.

Answer (score 2):

Надо понимать, что теоретически enumerator может оказаться сопрограммой, реализующей алгоритм произвольной сложности. Поэтому копировать внутреннее состояние в общем случае нельзя.

Comment: Теоретически понятно, а интересен был бы практический пример, в котором структура обоснованно нужна, и существенная часть инициализации внутренних структур обоснованно происходит после начала итерации.

Comment: @VladD любая сопрограмма может быть реализована структурой, ежели так захочет компилятор. Не забываем, что языков программирования - много.

Comment: Под сопрограммой вы имеете в виду те, которые автоматически получаются из методов с конструкцией `yield return`?

Comment: @VladD под сопрограммой я имею в виду любую реализацию той же самой идеи, что и методы с конструкцией yield return